# JQuery and AJAX form validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm pretty new to Javascript and PHP, but need to do a form validation for the user registration and I'm having trouble inserting the new user into the database.
I validate the form on the client side via JQuery's validation plugin and try to send a request to the database where I check the user availability via AJAX. The validation plugin works but something goes wrong when I requesting the database entries via AJAX, because if I press the "Send" button in the form I get the `Error occurred` alert on screen.

My registration.html code:

```
<form id="form" name="registration" action="" method="POST">
    <label for="user_name">Nickname:</label><br>
    <input type="input" size="40" maxlength="10" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="Nickname"><br><br>
    
    <label for="user_email">Email:</label><br>
    <input type="email" size="40" maxlength="20" name="user_email" id="user_email" placeholder="Email address"><br><br>
    <label for="user_password">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" size="40" maxlength="50" name="user_password" id="user_password" placeholder="Passwort"><br>

    <label for="confirmed_password">Confirm password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" size="40" maxlength="50" name="confirmed_password" id="confirmed_password" placeholder="Passwort bestätigen"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Send">
</form>
<script src="./form_validation.js"></script>
```

My form_validation.js code:

```
    $("#form[name='registration']").validate({
        rules: {
            user_name: {
                required: true
            },
            user_email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            user_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7
            },
            confirmed_password: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#user_password"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            user_name: 'Enter a nickname.',
            user_email: {
                required: 'Enter your email address.',
                email: 'Enter a valid email address.',
            },
            user_password: {
                required: 'Enter a password.',
                minLength: 'At least 7 characters.',
            },
            confirmed_password: {
                required: 'Confirm password.',
                equalTo: 'Passwords have to match.',
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            $.ajax({
                url:'./user.php',
                type: "post",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    alert("success");
                    console.log();
                    $("#result").html('Submitted');
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error occured");
                    console.log();
                    $("#result").html('An error occured while submitting.');
                }       
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My user.php code:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . "./connection.php";

if (isset($_POST["register"]) && isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['user_email']) && isset($_POST['user_password']) && isset($_POST['confirmed_password'])) 
{
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $user_password = $_POST['user_pasword'];

    $db = new DB_connection;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = :user_name OR user_email = :user_email";

    $statement = $db->conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam("user_name", $user_name);
    $statement->bindParam("user_email", $user_email);
    
    if ($statement->execute())
    {
        $sql =  "INSERT INTO user (user_name, user_pass, user_email) VALUES (:user_name, :user_password, :user_email)"; 

        $stmt = $db->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_name", $user_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_password", $user_password);
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_email", $user_email);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            echo "New user inserted";
        } else {
            echo "Something went wrong!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error!";
    }
}
```

Comment: if u get the error ocurred it means or the ajax url is wrong or something is wrong on server side, the ajax petition arrives to the server side ?

Comment: You can inspect the http requests with the development tools of your browser. Also there are some parameters available to your ajax error function, that should give you at least some hints of what is going on. `error: function(request, textStatus, errorText) {...}` See https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/

Comment: Ok, there is something wrong because no parameters are sent. Thanks for the link. @lupz

Comment: While client side validation can be very useful, you should always validate all inputs on the server side! See https://owasp.org/www-project-proactive-controls/v3/en/c5-validate-inputs#client-side-and-server-side-validation.

Comment: I know I just want to get it my AJAX requests to work on the client side at first.

Comment: "*no parameters are sent*" - do you mean none of your `user_*` params are sent in the POST? What does your browser devtools show, eg check the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I just had to replace the `include_once __DIR__ './connection.php';` with `include_once __DIR__ '/../config/config.php';`. What is strange is that no MYSQL error message appeared and other classes work without the `include_once` statement.